# Help Identifying a pale green, spherical squash-y like vegetable

Tags: food-identification, squash

Got it from the local co-op, no idea what it is! I assume it's some sort of squash.
It's about the size of a medium-large orange.

[image: some sort of squash. It's about the size of a medium-large orange]

Comment: That looks an awful lot like a honeydew melon, though it could be some sort of hybrid. It's hard to definitively identify without seeing the flesh, as the skin is basically identical to a honeydew.

Comment: How does it look on the inside ... and what are the taste and texture like? It could be a very young squash/pumpkin of many varieties ... but it is hard to say from the picture.

Comment: Looks like some kind of heirloom zucchini.

Comment: Sorry guys, was trying to figure out what it was before I cut it up so I could plan out recipes. Heirloom zucchini seems to be it -- it  did come side by side with another zucchini.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a **cue ball zucchini**.

It's similar to a **one ball zucchini** (yellow), and an **eight ball zucchini** (dark green, almost black). All of them are round and great squashes to stuff and roast. Hope you enjoyed it!

Answer (score 6):

The fruit from the Cucurbit family (pumpkins, squash, zucchini, melons, gourds etc) are all very good at cross pollinating. This will create some very strange fruits.

I have accidentally grown all kinds of odd things. I would imagine that they are more common at markets & places where people sell produce grown on smaller (than commercial scale production) plots or gardens. This is because proximity is a contributing factor with wind & insect pollination.

I don't recognise this particular one but it could easily be hybrid. Was it the only one of its type or was there a whole crate of them?

Comment: There was only one in the crate. I've of course long cut it up and cooked it, but thanks for the response!